# MVVM should i use INotifyPropertyChanged if the Object Property never changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i just started learning MVVM and i have the following model

```
class ResultModel : MyMVVMBase
    {
        #region Field
        private string _name;
        #endregion


        #region Poperties
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                SetField(ref _name, value, "Name");
            } 
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

MyMVVMBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged

for this model the value is set only once when the model is created and it never changes, should it still Iimplement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't strictly need to support `INotifyPropertyChanged` for that property (or at all, if that's the only public property), as long as you always fully initialize the models before binding.

Comment: so in this case i could simply use an automatic property?

Comment: There been some rumors about memory leak, I believe they fixed it by now [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx)

Comment: http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/10/detecting_bindings_that_should_be_onetime.html here are some more information